# In large PHP projects with multiple databases and Memcached, do the developers have these things on their local development machine?

Tags: php, web

In large PHP projects with many developers where the project requires several databases, perhaps a SQL and NoSQL database, plus memcached, would the developers on the team have these databases and memcached on their local development machines? Or are these services simply mocked out and then integrated with later?

Comment: For what it's worth, we have _development servers_ that are kept mostly in-syncish with the live environment. I'd shriek back at the horror of making it every developers _personal responsibility_ to keep up with the changes/settings in live environments, IMO that's asking for errors or performance issues on integration because someone forgot to update something. And quite frankly, maintaining databases et al. is knowledge most developers strictly do not need, basic knowledge is a plus, but let the sysadmins do _their_ job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) to get new employees (or everybody) up and running within minutes.

If you need big databases (like milions of rows of data not just simple schema with some data) to work you can always setup them locally in cluster but if one person will break something other developers are going to feel that ;)

Comment: I like this answer, I hadn't heard of Vagrant. I also don't see how this question isn't "constructive." This is a best practices question, and I found the answer given to be helpful. I think in many cases the stack overflow rigid Q&A "rules" are a disservice to the entire community of people trying to learn.